# Laravel error: jQuery.easing is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-6

I have a laravel project in which I want to use jQuery UI for smooth transitions and effects. I added the `jquery-ui.js` to the `public/js` folder. The same as my current jQuery file which works as intended.

I imported the javascript file in my blade template like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/animate.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/jquery-ui.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to call the toggle function on a button click I get the following error:

> app.js:14040 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function

While regular jQuery works fine, jQuery UI does not.

**Main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#slide-next').on('click', function() {
        $('.register-form-user').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
});
```

All my paths are correct. When downloading the jQuery UI file I made sure I selected all the available options including easing.

What is causing this error?

**Bootstrap.js**

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

// window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
//     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
//     encrypted: true
// });
```

Comment: You're including `js/app.js` twice, first is deferred in the header and second is at the bottom before closing tag of the body

Comment: That does not make a difference @Saly3301

Comment: It might, is jquery included in your bootstrap.js file?

Comment: I edited the question with the bootstap.js file. It is in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery is already included in your app.js bundle from the boostrap.js file. The last call to app.js in your html overrides the previous instance of jquery, making it load after jQuery UI. jQuery must be loaded before jquery-ui.

Change this

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

To this

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

and remove the deferred script tag from your `<head>` section